# .htaccess - Deny all except one folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ftp

I am trying to deny all connections to my website using .htaccess that looks something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403\.php

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/errors/403\.php$" HANDLE403
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 188.167.150.5
allow from 78.145.188.71
allow from env=HANDLE403  

AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php52
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
```

The .htaccess file is stored in the root folder of my ftp and this works fine, however I want to use custom Error 403 page which is saved in Errors folder on the same ftp, so basically it gets blocked too. I have tried to create a new .htaccess in the Errors folder (as suggested in other topics) with this code:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all

AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php52
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
```

But it still doesn't work and I get just the default 403 page with "Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Any idea how I could fix this, so that the error files are accessible by all, while the rest is denied for all except few specific IPs?

Comment: Is it `/errors` or `/Errors`?

Comment: /errors sorry for the confusion in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your custom handler like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 188.167.150.5
allow from 78.145.188.71
```

Comment: This behaves in a strange way.. for some reason it allowed me to see any page and didn't give me 403 error

Comment: Ok let me test it one more time.

Comment: It fixed the "allow for all" problem, but now the errors/403.php is again forbidden with message "Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: That is strange since I tested it on my localhost with just above code. Do you have some other code as well in your .htaccess?

Comment: Nope, just your code plus the 3 AddType lines that I've mentioned

Comment: OK Can you dump your latest .htaccess in your question again?

Comment: Actually I found out why you're getting that error. It is because in your system `/errors/403.php` is not a valid file. See my updated answer correct 403 line will be: **`ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php`** and **make sure** that `/errors/403.php` exists in your system.